# Django psycopg2 template return

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i am searching some words in remote database with python psycopg2 module and than append them in list then taking it django template .. i have problem with how can i get third and eight object from list

my view.py:

```
result=[]
....
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   result.append(row)

return render_to_response("search/se.html",{"data":"res":result}})
```

in my se.html

```
{% for ress in data.res %}
      {{ ress }}
{% endfor %}
```

here, i get all searched column of row from my database , but i want as django filter queryset result

```
{{ ress.id }}
{{ ress.name }}
```

thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry misread the question.
Try starting from this

```
def fields(cursor):
    results = {}
    column = 0
    for d in cursor.description:
        results[d[0]] = column
        column = column + 1

    return results
```

as you can see you can modify my code to get out your 3rd and 8th columns as list

also [this snippet](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL#Select.2FFetch_Records_with_Column_Names) may be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

That's my first answer. I hope it's the right one^^

Instead of a for loop i would take while loop.

```
result1 = []
result2 = []

rows = cur.fetchone()
while rows:
     result1.append(row[2])    # takes all third objects of the list
     result2.append(row[7])    # takes all eight .....
     rows = cur.fetchone()
```

This works in normal Python. I hope in Django too.

Comment: thank you for your help i have learned we can call second object of list in django template as {{ ress.2 }} ...